# Assigning a unique class to individual radio inputs using Simple Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, input, radio-button, simple-form

I have a pair of radio inputs that I'd like to individually add unique class to. I'm aware of using `input_html {class: "example-class"}` but I need both classes to be different. So for instance:

```
<input type="radio" class="male" value="male">
<input type="radio" class="female" value="female">
```

I've read through the documentation for Simple Form and multiple posts here on SO but still can't seem to find a solution. Instead answers only lead to assigning one basic class to a label and/or its children inputs. This is currently how my radio buttons are setup:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [['male', 'male'] ,['female', 'female']], :first, :last %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block around like :

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [['male', 'male'] ,['female', 'female']], :first, :last do |b|
      b.label { b.radio_button(class: (b.value == 'male' ? 'male' : 'female' )) }
    end
%>
```

Read the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) of this method:

> .. It is also possible to customize the way the elements will be shown by giving a block to the method:

Comment: I got the syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')' `

Comment: Works now thanks. Would you happen to know why it removes the labels for the inputs when this is done in block format?

Comment: @CarlEdwards may be due to `b.label`.. try only `b.radio_button(class: (b.value == 'male' ? 'male' : 'female' ))`..

Comment: btw, you can define the label using the `b.label` method itself.. Read the last part of the linked documentation..

Comment: Strange. The `<label/>`  element still appears in the source even after omitting `b.label` from the block: `b.radio_button(class: (b.value == 'male' ? 'male' : 'female' ))`. I wonder why.

Comment: I saw [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8cc60d81363069710e277ed03fdbaf8872895f1e/actionpack/test/template/form_helper_test.rb#L1123) also, where I found you can't avoid the label with the _block_ version it seems..

Comment: Unfortunately `item_wrapper_tag: nil` didn't remove the labels.